# Docker NGINX Reverse Proxy 502 Bad Gateway on VM

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to setup a Gitea instance on a VM.
For that I am using docker-compose.

Now my problem is, that i run my VM and docker-compose but I can't reach the webapp. The browser prompts me with a `502 Bad Gateway`.

The IP for my VM is: 192.168.33.10.
In the browser I am typing in `192.168.33.10:80`

The `docker logs production_nginx` provides me with the following output:

```
2020/06/23 14:26:11 [error] 28#28: *7 connect() failed
 (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
 client: 192.168.33.1, server: , request: "GET / 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.27.0.2:3000/", host:
 "192.168.33.10"
192.168.33.1 - - [23/Jun/2020:14:26:11 +0000] "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux 
x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0"
```

However I don't understand what is happening here...
Any advide is highly appreciated.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

networks:
  proxy:
  gitea:
    external: false

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "222:22"
    networks:
      - proxy

  server:
    container_name: gitea_server
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=Gitea
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - DB_TYPE=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db:5432
      - DB_NAME=gitea
      - DB_USER=gitea
      - DB_PASSWD=gitea
      - DOMAIN=localhost
      - SSH_DOMAIN=localhost
      - HTTP_PORT=80
      - SSH_PORT=22
      - SSH_LISTEN_PORT=22
    restart: always
    networks:
      gitea:
        aliases:
          - gitea_server
      proxy:
        aliases:
          - gitea_server
    volumes:
      - gitea_data:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "2222"
    depends_on:
        - db

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gitea
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitea
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitea
    networks:
      - gitea
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  gitea_data: {}
  postgres: {}
```

My nginx.conf:

```
events {}
http {
  upstream gitea{
    server gitea_server:3000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://gitea;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the user inside the `gitea` image is not allowed to use ports <= 1023.

```
server_1  | 2020/06/23 17:20:49 ...s/graceful/server.go:55:NewServer() [I] Starting new server: tcp:0.0.0.0:80 on PID: 14
server_1  | 2020/06/23 17:20:49 ...s/graceful/server.go:79:ListenAndServe() [E] Unable to GetListener: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: permission denied
server_1  | 2020/06/23 17:20:49 cmd/web.go:204:runWeb() [C] Failed to start server: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: permission denied
server_1  | 2020/06/23 17:20:49 cmd/web.go:206:runWeb() [I] HTTP Listener: 0.0.0.0:80 Closed
```

Just put `HTTP_PORT=3000` and you are good to go.